# How to check whether a user is assigned with a url?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2.I want to check whether a user is assigned with a url.if a user try to access url which not assigned to him by the admin,'access denied' message should be displayed.
i will show my comntroller

```
 public function checkUrl(){

        $current_link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//current link

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, '/');

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, 'cable');

        $current_link=ltrim($current_link, '/');        

        $dlink = Roles::where('link',$current_link)->pluck('id');//current link id

        $elink=Auth::user()->id;//current user id

        if($elink == $dlink)
        {

        Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Access Denied!!'));

         return redirect()->action('Admin\DashboardController@index');
             }

          }
```

Comment: are you getting any error ? What are `dlink` and `elink` variables are for ?

Comment: $dlink is for getting current link id and $elink is for current user id

Comment: sorry I missed the comments in your code.. Is this not working ? I didn't understand the issue

Comment: if a user try to access a url which is not assigned to him by the admin,access denied msg should be displayed in the page

Comment: yes.. that's right .. is your current code not working ? this seems to be very broad question to answer.. since I'm unaware of your database design and all.. It would be a good idea if you could point me towards the issue you are facing

Comment: the if condition is correct?when running access denied msg is shown but user can access   the page.the page access should be stopped.

Comment: your coding does not make any sense  `$dlink` holds role id and `$elink` holding user id!  how could both same? ?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options for denying the access in this scenario.

1) Create a page showing "Access Denied Msg" and other details that you want to include and return this page if access is denied.
for example, consider that the page created is `access_denied.blade.php` then your if condition would look like below:

```
if($elink == $dlink)
    {
        Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Access Denied!!'));
        return view("access_denied");
    }
```

2) Since, you are redirecting the request to another action, handle access related response there.

3) Send abort response as given [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/202/throwing-httpexceptions).